# Hazelcast map fifo eviction

Tags: hazelcast, fifo, evict

Need to set a FIFO eviction policy on hazelcast Map. The idea is when the heap is occupied with 90% memory, the system will start freeing up oldest data. LRU and LFU does not work and the system can fill up 90% within minutes as well while not being accessed one. Any ideas would be welcome.
FYI we are using java client for hazelcast map.

Answer (score -1):

You should never have heap utilization of 90% since the GC will kick in all the time. Depending on GC combination used it should be between 50 and 70%.

In terms of Hazelcast configuration, which version do you use?

Comment: using hazelcast 3.5.1